# SQL: How to update values of table one and implement the change in table 2 as welll?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have two tables, and i am trying to update the first table based on the value from second table. Table 1 contains the Sum of total weight and table two contains weight. when added up these values in table 2, it then shows total in table 1

For example if I update the foreign key in table 2 then the Amount in table should update. Please refer the screenshot attached.

[image]

My first table sql:

```
select LodingZoneID, Finaltotal from TransitList
```

My Second table sql:

```
SELECT  `Suburb`, `LodingZoneID`, Total FROM `GenerateRun`
```

Comment: We don't normally store derived data

Comment: @Strawberry , the data in table 2 is first added and then inserted into the table one with insert query. I am not doing any SUM or calculating with the select query

Comment: Yes, so why not get rid of table one?

Comment: Yes, you are right. That may solve my problem

Comment: From the backticks I conclude you're using MySQL not SQL Server. I removed the wrong tag for you. Also please don't post images of tables. Use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements.

Comment: @stickybit u sound bit hostile

Comment: Some people think they are over smart and dont think if they are new or dont have experience. Just want to show faults rather than helping each other. This is the reason, I cant ask any questions as my account is blocked

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for table 1.  You can just run the query:

```
select fk, sum(val)
from table2
group by fk;
```

If you really need to store the sum in table 1, then you would be using triggers on table2 to handle `insert`/`update`/`delete`.  This is rather cumbersome and it is generally better to do the calculation when needed, rather than trying to store the results in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### Or, You can create a View with desired output

-CREATE VIEW 'TransitList' AS
SELECT LodingZoneID, SUM(Total) FinalTotal FROM GenerateRun
GROUP BY LodingZoneID;

#### Whenever you want to access data, you can use

-SELECT LodingZoneID, FinalTotal  FROM TransitList;